# NSTextField setAlphaValue - nothing happens

Tags: cocoa, alpha, nstextfield

When I run this code:

...

```
//draw the page
    thisPage = [[Page alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(25.0, 25.0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height)];
    [masterPage addSubview:thisPage];

    //get the positioning for the page number
    NSRect pageFrame = [thisPage frame];
    float xPos = pageFrame.size.width/2-pageFrame.size.width/4;
    float yPos = pageFrame.size.height/2-pageFrame.size.height/4;

    NSTextField* thisPageNum = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(xPos, yPos, 50.0, 50.0)];
    [thisPageNum setTextColor: [NSColor purpleColor]];
    [thisPageNum setAlphaValue:0.1];
    [thisPageNum setBordered: NO];
    [thisPageNum setEditable: NO];
    [thisPageNum setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", p+1]];
    [thisPageNum setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:36.0]];
    [thisPageNum setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [thisPage addSubview:thisPageNum];
```

when the textfield is added there is no opacity to it at all. Why is that?

Comment: What is the target SDK? It works for me with 10.7 SDK. Try adding `[thisPageNum setWantsLayer:YES]` before setting the alpha value.

Answer (score 1):

You  are setting setDrawsBackground as NO. This will naturally render the text field as transparent.

Removing that should help you get the desired result.